# TypeError even converted

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I tried to make a limit calculator but Python keeps on telling me this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\practice1.py", line 44, in submit
    print(type(str(limit+1))==type(12))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

My code is here:

```
import re
from math import *
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()
root.title('Limit')
root.geometry('300x300')

lab=Label(text='This is limit calculator.\nCheck out the functions to use in the command line.')
explain=Label(text='limit as x goes to...')
entry=Entry()
Expl=Label(text='The equation is...')
lim=Entry()


print('''X to the power of y is typed in as x**y,
x times y is typed in as x*y, and
x divided by y is typed in as x/y.
You can also use functions like:
    1. trigonometry functions like sin, asin, asinh, cos, etc
    2. ceil (ceiling function) and floor

    3. degrees (radians to degrees) and radians (degrees to radians)
    4. fabs (decimal absolute value)
    5. factorial and gamma
    6. log (type log ( number, base))
    7. sqrt (square root)
    8. e and pi
    9. boolean operators
    10. other minor functions''')

def submit():
    a=str(entry.get())
    limit=lim.get()
    entry.delete(0,'end')
    lim.delete(0,'end')

    if 'x' not in a:
        lab.configure(text=str(eval(a)))
        return None

    print(type('x')==type(12))
    print(type(str(limit+1))==type(12))
    print(type(a)==type(1))
    b=re.sub('x',str(limit+1),a)
    c=re.sub('x',str(limit-1),a)
    try:
        ans1=eval(b)
        ans2=eval(c)
        ans_fin=(ans1+ans2)/2
        lab.configure(text=str(ans_fin))
    except Exception:
        b1=eval(re.sub(str(limit+1),b))
        b2=eval(re.sub(str(limit-1),b))
        c1=eval(re.sub(str(limit+1),c))
        c2=eval(re.sub(str(limit-1),c))
        cans=(c1+c2)/2
        bans=(b1+b2)/2
        real_ans=(cans+bans)/2
        lab.configure(text=str(real_ans))

button=Button(text='Calculate!',command=submit)

lab.pack()
explain.pack()
lim.pack()
Expl.pack()
entry.pack()

button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Please state the error that causes this program to malfunction.
I am a starter in Python. If possible, please state where these errors are found and how to fix them.

This is all the information I got.

My computer is Windows 10, 64-bit.

Comment: please don't link to code on another site. You need to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your `limit` object is `str`, not `int`, so you cannot add 1 to it.
You can try:

```
print(type(str(int(limit)+1))==type(12))
```

If limit is supposed to be an `int`.

Comment: Thanks, but the traceback states that the error was that it was a integer, not a string.

Comment: Yes, because you are trying to add an integer to a string.

Comment: you could've also written limit + "1" so it is two strings, but string addition is probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That magically worked! I wonder why it is not an integer already because I already converted the input into an integer the moment I made the variable.